# Start counting indexes from 1 instead of 0 of a list

Tags: python-3.x, max, counting

I created a program to get the the max value of a list and the position of its occurrences (list starting at indexing with 1 not 0) but I can't manage to find any useful solutions.
The input is always a string of numbers divided by zero.

This is my code:

```
inp = list(map(int,input().split()))
m = max(inp)
count = inp.count(m)
print(m)
def maxelements(seq): # @SilentGhost
    return [i for i, j in enumerate(seq) if j == m]
print(maxelements(inp))
```

I expect to output the maximum value and then all the positions of its occurrences. (also is it possible to do without brackets as in the example below?)

Input: `4 56 43 45 2 56 8`

Output: `56`

`2 6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to shift index values, you could just do

```
return [i + 1 for i, j in enumerate(seq) if j == m]
```

more generally any transformation of i or j!

```
def f(i, j):
    # do whatever you want, and return something
    return i + 1

return [f(i, j) for i, j in enumerate(seq) if j == m]
```

Without brackets, as a string:

```
return " ".join(str(i + 1) for i, j in enumerate(seq) if j==m)
```

Comment: i got "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found" message

Answer (score 1):

Specifiy `start=1` with [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> l = [4, 56, 43, 45, 2, 56, 8]
>>> max_num = max(l)
>>> [i for i, e in enumerate(l, start=1) if e == max_num]
[2, 6]
```

By default `enumerate()` uses `start=0`, because indices start at 0.